# Heroku Error: Websockets and ssl-endpoint features misconfiguration

Tags: ssl, heroku, websocket

I'm trying to enable websockets for an app on Heroku. I added the SSL add-on first, so it would not allow me to `heroku labs:enable websockets`. I removed the SSL add-on as well as the domain, however when I run `heroku labs:enable websockets`.

Is there any way to enable websockets on this app, or would I need to create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, you must follow a specific order.

> Custom SSL Endpoints can be provisioned with WebSocket support. The
>   websockets labs feature must be enabled before the endpoint has been
>   provisioned though.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets

I had the same problem, I solved with :

- remove custom domain certs
- remove ssl addon
- enable sockets
- add ssl addon
- add custom domain certs